# Comparison of results given by volatility estimators: Garman-Klass Vs Garch(1,1)

Tags: volatility, programming, garch

I am pretty new with volatility estimators and I am trying to see if Garman-Klass estimator and Garch(1,1)estimator are closed.
So I implemented a python code for the two estimators (an also for the realized volatility estimator as standard deviation of squared returns), but testing it on Tesla data, I have a huge difference between them. That means that my understanding (or my implementation) of these estimators is false. I have unsuccessfully searched for errors.

Below is the python code:

```
import math
import pandas as pd 
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import date 
import yfinance as yf
from arch import arch_model

observation_period=10# number of months from the last available day
df =  yf.download("TSLA")
df=df.last('%dm'%observation_period)

def annualized_realized_volatility_estimator(df,window_length=observation_period, unit_window_length='m', A=252):
    temp=A*(1/len(df))*np.log(df.last('%d'%observation_period+unit_window_length)).diff().dropna()
    V=temp['Adj Close'].sum() 
    return math.sqrt(V)


def Garman_Klass_estimator_row(H, L, O, C,T=len(df.index), A=252):
    V=A*(1/T)*(1/2)*(math.log(H/L))**2 - (2*math.log(2)-1)*(math.log(C/O))**2
    return V
def Garman_Klass_estimator(df):
    vol=math.sqrt(df.apply(lambda row:Garman_Klass_estimator_row(row['High'], row['Low'], row['Open'], row['Close']),axis=1).sum())
    return vol


def Garch_model(df,training_period,observation_period,horizon=1): #training_period is the number of months for training the Garch
    df_garch=df.last('%dm'%(observation_period+training_period))
    df_garch_train=df_garch.first('%dm'%training_period)
    df_garch_predict=df_garch.last('%dm'%observation_period)
    df_garch_train.loc[:,'Returns']=100 * df_garch_train.loc[:,'Adj Close'].pct_change().dropna()
    garch11 = arch_model(df_garch_train.loc[:,'Returns'].dropna(), p=1, q=1) 
    res = garch11.fit(update_freq=10) 
    forecasts = res.forecast(horizon=horizon)
    return 0.1*forecasts.residual_variance.iloc[-1].values[-1]
```

Calling the three functions with:

```
annualized_realized_volatility_estimator(df,window_length=10, unit_window_length='m', A=252)
Garman_Klass_estimator(df)
Garch_model(df,training_period=6,observation_period,horizon=1)
```

I obtained the following results:

annualized_realized_volatility_estimator=1.643

Garman_Klass_estimator=0.632

Garch_model=2.256

Could someone explain the notable differences between these estimators? Especially between the Garman Klass estimator and the Garch estimator?

Also the code python for the Garch(1,1) is it well-done?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: A few ways to help yourself: 1. Read documentation of the packages you're using and make sure you have implemented all of the functions correctly. 2. In general, when verifying whether your volatility estimators are correct, you do not compare them using real world data. Instead you simulate stock prices following eg. a GBM and see whether all of the estimators provide estimates that converges towards your specified volatility parameter, $\sigma$, for large samples. 3. Google if anyone has implemented the estimators before you (Github is a good place to start), and learn from others code.

Comment: Thanks for the advices